# Laravel - URLs with ID and slugs - convenient way to link to something

Tags: php, laravel

I a blog with comments which are linked to from different part of my sites. To link to a comment, please look at my routes file first.

My route file:

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{id}/{slug}'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'BlogController@show')->name('blog.show');
        Route::get('edit', 'BlogController@edit')->name('blog.edit');
        Route::post('edit', 'BlogController@save')->name('blog.edit.save');
        Route::get('comments/{id}', 'BlogController@commentEdit')->name('blog.comments.edit');
        Route::post('comments/{id}', 'BlogController@commentSave')->name('blog.comments.save');
    }
```

The problem isn't the routes. It's the views and the forms. To link to a single comment, I have to do this.

```
    <a href="{{ route('blog.comments.edit', [$comment->blog->id, $comment->blog->slug, $comment->id]) }}"> View Comment </a>
```

As you can see, it's a pain trying to link to a comment. How can I do this better? Imagine having 20 of those all throughout my site.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not create your own helper that accepts the comment object as its parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could delegate it to your comment model.

In your Comment model:

```
public function getUrlParams() {
  return [
     $this->blog->id,
     $this->blog->slug,
     $this->id
  ];
}
```

Then in your view:

```
  <a href="{{ route('blog.comments.edit', $comment->getUrlParams()) }}"> View Comment </a>
```